# Programming language with UI to learn for a C developer

Tags: c, user-interface, window

I want to learn UI programming, you know like windows applications such as chrome, firefox and many others, and i already know C.
So what language should i learn next?

Comment: C# or Java perhaps? What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a GUI toolkit, not a new language. If you want to stick with C, [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) is a decent library and works on Windows, Linux and OS X. If you want to move to C++, [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) does everything you could ask for (and also runs on Windows, Linux and OS X). If you want to stick with only Windows, I suggest using something like C# because it is incredibly easy to develop WinForm applications. If you want to stick with only OS X, learn Objective-C and use Xcode to build GUI applications quickly.

There are a multitude of answers to this question. Search the web for "GUI library" or "GUI toolkit" and you will find existing threads on SO that explain the differences in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C background and want to build Windows applications, then you would probably benefit from developing in C++ or C#.

C++ has the advantage of being somewhat platform-independent, in that you could then also program for linux/mac.

C# is also useful if you ever want to do a lot of web programming.

Both languages have huge support communities online.